# Declaring variables dynamically within PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql

The program is to extract numbers from an input string. Eg: ab123cde4f. Now if only the input string has numbers then I will declare a variable of number datatype (to extract the numbers) after checking for numbers within the Begin..End block. If there are no numbers I will not declare any variable and simply give dbms output that the input string does not contain any numbers. Suggest a pl/sql block.

Comment: at stack overflow you are advised to attempt to write some code first

Comment: @tapabrata Why do you not want to declare any variable?

Comment: Clearly the right approach is to declare a variable of numeric datatype but **not to use it** if the input doesn't contain any numbers.

Comment: Can any variable be declared within the Begin End block in a PL/SQL program?? I completely agree that the proper approach would be to declare a variable of numeric datatype and use it if my conditions are found to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your questions is, if a variable can be declared within a `BEGIN...END block`. No, you always need a `declare` block for that.

However you can use declare inside a `BEGIN...END` Block as well.

```
BEGIN
    IF 1=1 THEN
        DECLARE
            v_chr VARCHAR2(100) := 'hello';
        BEGIN
            dbms_output.put_line(v_chr);
        END;
    ELSE
        DECLARE
            v_chr VARCHAR2(100) := 'world';
        BEGIN
            dbms_output.put_line(v_chr);
        END;
    END IF;
END;
```

I wouldn't suggest it though, its much more *KISS* thingy to just define a variable.